# How can I search tags in python with python-gitlab plugin?

Tags: python, gitlab

Now I'm using python-gitlab:1.0.0 to do some gitlab operations in python, but I soon found I can't search tags with the python-gitlab plugin.

Api doc here: http://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gl_objects/projects.html#project-tags

Is there any way to search gitlab tags in python? Or maybe there is another plugin I can use?

Comment: "Searching" tags doesn't appear to be supported by the [gitlab api itself](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/tags.html). I think you get the list of all available tags and then perform the filtering yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To @larsks point, GitLab api does not support tag searching.  You can search other objects, such as `Projects`, but tags are not supported currently.  You can create an iteration to loop over the tags returned, something like:

```
import gitlab

# private token authentication
gl = gitlab.Gitlab('http://10.0.0.1', 'JVNSESs8EwWRx5yDxM5q')

# make an API request to create the gl.user object. This is mandatory if you
# use the username/password authentication.
gl.auth() 

# Get a single project by team/project name
project = gl.projects.get('myteam/myproject')

# get all tags associated with the single project returned
tags = project.tags.list()

# iterate over tags from tag list retrieved
for tag in tags:
    if tag in ('bug', 'defect', 'feature'):
         # do something here based on these tags...
```

Hopefully, this helps.

Comment: In fact I have done this yesterday, but still thanks for your answer :)

Comment: By the way, do you know how to get tags by pages? I have tried to use `tags = project.tags.list(per_page=5, page=1)` to get paged tags but i still get all tags :(

Comment: I don't have an active instance of `gitlab` for testing currently, and my answer above was literally pieced together from reading through the docs (I've never actually implemented this code before).  But the docs have this page that may help guide you in the right direction: http://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/gitlab.v3.html#gitlab.v3.objects.ProjectTagManager

Comment: This gets hang for me